# PHP read body into byte array without using unpack

Tags: php, arrays

Im writing a PHP script to run in apache2.  I'm getting a byte array from a device that I need to parse into an object.  When I do a $body = file_get_contents('php://input'), I get a string.  Then I need to do a funky unpack('C*', $body).  Now I have an array that has an extra element in the beginning, from the unpack process.  It seems I'm trying too hard to do something that seems trivial.

Is there a way to just read the body as a byte array, and skip all the string conversion garbage?  Come on PHP!  Its just an array of bytes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trust me, believe or not there are no specific byte containers in PHP.  You are doing it in the correct way. I have developed several binary algorithms in this language, it's really hard to understand when you come from other languages like C++ or Delphi.

In PHP the standard byte array container is the string. For example:

```
$myVar = file_get_contents("/folder/myfile.bin");
```

In this case myVar acts as string and also as array of bytes.

The only way to change bytes representation is performing pack and unpack operations.

```
$myByteArray= unpack("N*",$myvar); 
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($myByteArray); $i++)
{ 
    echo $myByteArray[$i].'<br/>'; 
}
```

Here you have some good explanations:

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch01_14.htm

http://www.codediesel.com/php/unpacking-binary-data/

And let me give you a last tip based on my experience: if you plan to migrate your PHP application to many different hardware arquitectures, take care of endianess on pack/unpack operations.

Comment: I've got it figured out, thanks for the help.  I've just create a wrapper around upack that gives me a nice zero index array.  I've also added a non-zero pad to the end of my packet, as I couldn't figure out how to use the "a" option with unpack to not ignore trailing zeros.